# C++ Calling virtual functions from the constructor - is there a better alternative to this?

Tags: c++, constructor, virtual-functions

I'd like to introduce my own 'exceptions' into my code(I don't want to use std::exception because I want to differentiate between std exceptions and my own exceptions - I'll catch and handle them seperately), so I built a basic CPPException class:

```
    class CPPException {
        const char* source = nullptr;
    public:

        CPPException(const char* src) {
            source = src;
        }
        CPPException(void) = delete;
        ~CPPException() = default;

        virtual const char* what() = 0;
        const char* where() { return source; }
        void LogException() {
            Logger::LogError(R"(Got a CPP Exception in "%s" : %s)", where(), what());
        }
    };
```

I would like to log all my exceptions upon construction but issue is that you cannot call virtual functions inside constructors.
So I have to call LogException in all my child classes' constructors.

```
class BadAlloc : public CPPException {
public:
    virtual const char* what() { return "bad alloc"; }
    BadAlloc(const char* src) : CPPException(src) {
        LogException();
    }
};
```

Is there a better way?
I'd like something like this:
`CPPException::CPPException(const char* src){source = src;LogException();}`
and then in my child classes just inherit that constructor, so that I don't have to write LogException in every single child class(but that of course won't work because LogException calls virtual function 'what' and at the moment of CPPException::CPPException constructor that function is pure virtual).
I even tried directly obtaining the VMT from 'this' ptr and calling functions from there but the funny thing is that the following code:

```
try {
    throw BadAlloc("myfunc");
}
catch (CPPException&) {}
```

does not even build an instance of BadAlloc. only CPPException is constructed(judging by RTTI and, of course, the functions in the VMT).
So imagine this: I have lots of different classes based on CPPException and I'll have to write LogException in every single constructor. Is there a different approach for this? I don't want to log them in catch blocks, I want to log them when they're thrown.
I could theoretically use preprocessor to define each and every class seperately without any sort of inheritance but I hate preprocessor.

Comment: "*I don't want to use std::exception because I want to differentiate between std exceptions and my own exceptions - I'll catch and handle them seperately*" - you can and should derive custom exceptions from `std::exception`. You can still differentiate between different exception types using explicitly-typed `catch` blocks, or `dynamic_cast`.

Comment: "*I even tried directly obtaining the VMT from 'this' ptr and calling functions from there*" - that won't work, since `this` inside the base constructor is pointing at the base class's VMT, it does not point at the derived class's VMT as the derived class hasn't been constructed yet. Only the derived class's constructor (and its descendant constructors) will be able to access the derived class's VMT.

Comment: You could have your subclass-constructor call `what()` and pass the returned value up to the `CPPException` constructor as a second argument; that would solve the virtual-method-call problem (although you'd have to be careful to handle subclasses-of-subclasses properly, i.e. by providing a suclass-constructor that takes a second argument as well so that its own subclasses can pass in their own what-string to it)

Comment: "*the following code: ...does not even build an instance of BadAlloc*" - yes, it does.  The `BadAlloc` portion of the object simply does not exist yet when the `CPPException` constructor is running.

Comment: I see, thanks for all the comments. But calling what() and passing it to the base constructor is still as much of a hassle as calling LogException. although it certainly would look neater. And yes I will make CPPException inherit from std::exception, thanks, it can indeed still be caught explicitly